# Где изъян в алгоритме из задачи с Codeforces? PascalABC.NET

Tags: алгоритм, pascalabc.net

На соревновании Codeforces Round #662 (Div. 2) попалась задача "Эпплджек и хранилища". Алгоритм я придумал не самый быстрый, но понятный. Реализовав его на языке PascalABC.NET, я отправил его на проверку. Результат - Неправильный ответ на претест 2. Соревнование закончилось два часа назад, до сих пор не могу понять в чём проблема.

Само задание:

Этот год в Эквестрии выдался урожайным, и Эпплджек захотела построить новые хранилища для яблок. По советам проектировщиков фермы она решила построить два хранилища ненулевой площади: одно в форме квадрата, другое в форме прямоугольника (который, возможно, тоже является квадратом).

Хранилища Эпплджек будет строить из досок, на каждую сторону хранилища она собирается потратить ровно одну доску. Доски она может заказать в одной фирме у своего приятеля. Изначально на складе фирмы есть n досок, длины которых Эпплджек известны. Работа фирмы не стоит на месте, она периодически получает заказы и сама заказывает новые доски. Приятель Эпплджек может предоставить ей информацию о всех операциях. Для удобства он будет сообщать информацию в следующем формате:

`+ x` — на склад поступила доска с длиной x
`− x` — со склада отгрузили доску с длиной x (при этом гарантируется, что на складе были какие-то доски длины x)
Эпплджек пока не определилась, когда она будет заказывать доски, поэтому она хочет после каждого события на складе знать, может ли она заказать доски, чтобы построить прямоугольное и квадратное хранилища. Эпплджек занята сбором яблок, поэтому у нее нет времени на подсчеты, и она попросила вас помочь ей!

Напоминаем, что у квадрата все четыре стороны равны, а у прямоугольника две пары равных сторон.

Входные данные
Первая строка содержит одно целое число n (1≤n≤105) — изначальное количество досок на складе фирмы, вторая строка содержит n целых чисел a1,a2,…,an (1≤ai≤105) — длины досок.

Третья строка содержит одно целое число q (1≤q≤105) — количество событий в фирме. Каждая из следующих q строк содержит описание событий в данном формате: сначала идет тип события (символ + или −), а затем число x (1≤x≤105).

Выходные данные
После каждого события на фирме выведите «YES», если из досок на складе фирмы можно собрать два хранилища нужной формы, и «NO» иначе (без кавычек). Вы можете выводить каждую букву в любом регистре (строчную или заглавную).

Пример
входные данные

```
6
1 1 1 2 1 1
6
+ 2
+ 1
- 1
+ 2
- 1
+ 2
```

выходные данные

```
NO
YES
NO
NO
NO
YES
```

Примечание
После второго события Эпплджек может построить прямоугольное хранилище из досок с длинами 1, 2, 1, 2 и квадратное хранилище из досок с длинами 1, 1, 1, 1.

После шестого события Эпплджек может построить прямоугольное хранилище из досок с длинами 1, 1, 1, 1 и квадратное хранилище из досок с длинами 2, 2, 2, 2.

Вот сам код:

```
var
    n,q,i,ones,twos:LongInt;
    a:array [1..100000] of LongInt;
    query:array [1..100000] of string;
    yes:boolean;
begin
    readln(n);
    for i:=1 to n do
      read(a[i]);
    readln(q);
    for i:=1 to q do
      readln(query[i]);
      
    for i:=1 to n do
    begin
      if (a[i] = 1) then
       inc(ones)
      else 
       inc(twos);
    end;
    
    for i:=1 to q do
    begin
      if (query[i][1] = '-') then
      begin
       if (query[i][3] = '1') then
           dec(ones)
       else
           dec(twos);
      end
      else
      begin
       if (query[i][3] = '1') then
           inc(ones)
       else
           inc(twos);
      end;
      
      yes:= false;
      if (ones - 4 >= 0) then
      begin
       if ((ones - 6 >= 0) and (twos - 2 >= 0)) then
       begin
           yes:=true;
       end
       else if ((ones - 8 >= 0) or (twos - 4 >= 0)) then
       begin
           yes:=true;
       end;
      end;
      if (twos - 4 >= 0) then
      begin
       if ((ones - 2 >= 0) and (twos - 6 >= 0)) then
       begin
           yes:=true;
       end
       else if ((ones - 4 >= 0) or (twos - 8 >= 0)) then
       begin
           yes:=true;
       end;
      end;
      if (yes) then
       writeln('YES')
      else 
       writeln('NO');
      
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Но ведь Ваш код учитывает только доски длиной 1 и 2, а могут быть и другие

Comment: Вернее 1 и не 1 а не 1 и 2

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не правильное представление о вводных почему-то у вас возможны только 1 либо остальные которые вы инкрементируете на каждом введенном не 1.

Решение простое создайте массив `а` из 105 элементов и инкрементируете `а[i]` на каждый приход доски длины `i` или десрементируйте значение `a[i]` на каждый уход `i` длины доски соответственно. В итоге проверять существует ли в массиве `a` элементы у которых значение больше 4 и больше 2 и 2 либо больше 6 и 2 либо больше 8 вот и все

Comment: Массив длиной 10^5, так что проверка будет не сплошной проверкой.

Answer (score 0):

Да, спасибо Aziz Umarov и MBo за ваши ответы. Я не внимательно прочитал задание,  а я каждый раз перепроверял свой алгоритм. Можно сделать с помощью:

```
for i:=1 to n do
begin
  inc(planksLength[a[i]]);
end;
```